# Compression of Inverted index using blocked compression

Tags: python, search-engine, information-retrieval

I have built an inverted index dictionary of text collection and need to compress dictionary using blocked compression k=8 and in posting file,gaps between docids using gamma encoding

```
   def createCompressedIndex(dictionary_uncomp_v1):
        for term in dictionary_uncomp_v1.keys():
             entry = dictionary_uncomp_v1.get(term)
             postingList = []
             prevId = 0
             pEntry = PostingEntry(0,0,0,0)
             for pEntry in entry.postingList:
                 docId = getGammaCode(pEntry.docId - prevId)
                 frequency = getGammaCode(pEntry.termFreq)
                 newPEntry = PostingEntry(docId,frequency,0,0)
                 postingList.extend(newPEntry)
                 prevId = pEntry.docId
                 ptemp = docId+frequency

             docFrequency = getGammaCode(entry.docFreq)
             entrytemp = ptemp+docFrequency
             totalTermFreq = getGammaCode(entry.totTermFreq)
             compressedEntry =  DictEntry(term,docFrequency,totalTermFreq,postingList)
             dictionary_comp_v1[term] = bytearray(entrytemp)
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have just concatenated the gamma codes of parameters and stored it in dictionary as bitarray. Is that a correct way to compress posting list?

Comment: How can I implement block compression k=8?